# Getting all records from Django's audit trail

Tags: django

I'm using Django's audit trail from [this site](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AuditTrail).

This is how I'm currently accessing my history:

```
for m in MyModel.objects.all() :
    for h in m.history.all() :
        print h
```

This results in an SQL query per model in my database. Is it possible to get all of the history elemts with a single SQL query?

EDIT: The regular method of prefetching related models isn't working:

```
MyModel.objects.prefetch_related('history')
```

raises a ValueError: `'history' does not resolve to a item that supports prefetching`

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation you linked

> The type of manager available depends on how you access the audit trail. From an instance, the audit trail will automatically be filtered to only return results related to that instance. From the model class itself, the results will not be filtered in any way, and is the likely approach for doing reporting across several audited items.

It sounds like you want to do the latter.  As `audit.AuditTrail` is not a `ForeignKey`, I wouldn't expect `prefetch_related` to work.  It sounds like you want to do

```
MyModel.history.all()
```

which will return all the history records in a single query.